# Rack server not hosting public ip?

Tags: ruby, ip, rack, host

I'm using a rack server (via [Hobbit](https://github.com/patriciomacadden/hobbit), which is similar to [Sinatra](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra)) to host a small web app.  For mobile testing, I've been starting my server with the command `rackup --host 0.0.0.0`, and visiting my mac's ip address and port # from my phone.

However suddenly my server is unreachable from my phone. I would guess some sort of update to Rack has caused this, but reverting to an old commit the problem persisted.  Perhaps doing so does not actually 'use' the old versions of the gems, but I thought this was the purpose of the Gemfile.lock?

Here is the new Gemfile:
https://gist.github.com/ErikAGriffin/5770b5dfcc2c36e9d98184b26d4fcd57
and the old:
https://gist.github.com/ErikAGriffin/ef05f7e493946d3a13ce528f9a1ca57c

Comment: Why should rack be the cause of this error? Did you check that your phone can reach your mac?

Comment: are you sucessfully visiting other apps on `0.0.0.0` from your phone? A quick fix might be to use `localtunnel` or `ngrok`

Comment: @slowjack2k I ran the traffic through ngrok and got all 200s, then tried via direct ip again and it worked.  Perhaps there was just some issue with my mac that was fixed by a simple restart... sigh